# Mapping resources to an application already installed

Tags: python, jython, websphere-8, wsadmin

I am fighting with a script in jython/python for Websphere Application Server 8.5 which has to map some resources, like Datasource, MailSessions, Queues and Activation Specifications, to an installed application.

I found on IBM Redbooks and IBM Knoledge Center how to install an application and mapping resources with a wsadmin command, but I have the application already installed and I do not have to unistall and reinstall the application.

This is what I found:

```
AdminApp.install('myapp.ear', ['-MapResRefToEJB',
[['deplmtest.jar', 'MailEJBObject', 'deplmtest.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml
mail/MailSession9', 'javax.mail.Session', 'jndi1', 'login1', 'authProps1',
'clientApplicationInformation=new application+clientWorkstation=9.10.117.65']]])
```

I found another wsadmin command, **AdminApp.edit**, but the only thing I did was to map the shared libraries with the following syntax:

```
AdminApp.edit(appName, ['-MapSharedLibForMod', [[name, module, library]]])
```

Could anyone tell me if I can use the **AdminApp.edit** command to map other resources? Or a source of inspiration where can I found the specific syntax with an example?

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is:

```
AdminApp.edit(appName, ['-MapResRefToEJB', [[module, bean, URI, jndi, type]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use exactly same syntax for `Admin.App.edit` like for `AdminApp.install`. Check these pages:

- [Commands for the AdminApp object using wsadmin scripting](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_adminapp.html?lang=en)
- [Options for the AdminApp object install, edit, update](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html?lang=en).The options listed in this topic apply to all of these commands except where noted.